# MySQL subquery returns false data

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having an issue with a subquery / union.

Here is what i want: i have a "backup table" (it is used for some purposes, not just backup) for orders, which i call dc_all_orders. I have two other tables, wb_orders and wb_printed. An order first gets into wb_orders and then, after a workflow step, it gets into wb_printed.
we have seen that some orderitems went missing, which we have in the backup table, but not in the two main order tables. I wanted to count the affected orderItems. I know 100% that the count should be more then 0, but it keeps returning zero. An example for an item which should count in:

```
mysql> select orderId,productId from dc_all_orders where productId = '22040247153891';
+---------------------+----------------+
| orderId             | productId      |
+---------------------+----------------+
| 20319833369460309A  | 22040247153891 |
+---------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (2.06 sec)


mysql> select * from wb_orders where productId = '22040247153891';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from wb_printed where productId = '22040247153891';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So this productId should show up. Now:

```
mysql> select count(*) from (select productId from wb_orders UNION select productId from wb_printed) as x;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  4295961 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2 min 51.80 sec)
```

So you know how much data we have.

```
mysql> select count(*) from dc_all_orders WHERE productId NOT IN 
    -> (select productId from wb_orders UNION select productId from wb_printed);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (11 min 9.20 sec)
```

I cannot explain it. I tried it with different ways, but every way shows 0. All i can think of is the size of the subquery, but i checked the logs, no error and as you see, results are returned without an error.

Am is missing the obvious? :)

Here is an other way:

```
mysql> select count(productId) from dc_all_orders WHERE productId NOT IN (select productId from wb_orders) AND  productId NOT IN (select productId from wb_printed);
+------------------+
| count(productId) |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (6 min 3.07 sec)
```

Edit: MySQL version: "Server version: 5.1.65-ius Distributed by The IUS Community Project" on a CentOS 5.8

Comment: What are the data types involved? Looks like you could be facing integer overflows...

Comment: The productId fields are varchars.

Comment: What if you just include one of both tables. does it work ?[select count(productId) from dc_all_orders WHERE productId NOT IN (select productId from wb_orders)] (I know it is not a solution, just to check what happens)

Comment: I did try this one, too, and the result is 0 as well.

Comment: FYI: i tried it with wb_orders as it is the smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the bottom of this, but MySQL does seem to have some kind of a size limit to the subquery that can be used with `IN (subquery)`. It's certainly not mentioned in ["restrictions on subqueries"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-restrictions.html) in the reference, but it's happened to me before. The solution was to write the query differently.

For example you could try to use `EXISTS (subquery)`:

```
select count(productId) from dc_all_orders a WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (select 1 from wb_orders o where a.productId = o.productId)
```

Or you can write the query with a `LEFT JOIN`, though this is a bit trickier (if you have multiple entries in `wb_orders` for a given `productId` you'll get duplicates; to remove duplicates you have to apply `group by` or `distinct` depending on what you want to do...)

```
select count(distinct a.productId) from dc_all_orders a LEFT JOIN wb_orders o 
    ON a.productId = o.productId WHERE o.id IS NULL
```